# Retain the value of primary key when using conflict strategy as REPLACE in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I created a SQLite table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE event 
(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
event_id TEXT NOT NULL, 
instance_id TEXT NOT NULL, 
...., 
UNIQUE (event_id, instance_id) ON CONFLICT REPLACE)
```

Now when there is a conflict while inserting, SQLite replaces the row with a new row, which in turn changes my primary key `_id`.

I don't want to change my primary key when it is replaced (on conflict). What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ON REPLACE` deletes the row with the conflict and inserts a new one. So, yes, the rowid is going to change unless it's included in the values being inserted.

If you're using sqlite 3.24 or newer, a different type of conflict resolution is available that allows you to update only certain columns when a particular unique constraint is violated. It's known as [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html). That's your best option for this case.

The other option involves trying to insert, detecting a uniqueness error, and doing an update instead. I'd only go this route if stuck on an old version.

Edit: obligatory do you *really* need [AUTOINCREMENT](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)?